# How to print out complex hash without repeating the second level keys?

Tags: perl, hash, perl-data-structures

Hi I have a hash of hash containing class name, number of students enrolled and the names of student.
How do I print out this hash without repeating the second level keys.
Example: My data that I fill in my hash is Science Class, 3 students enrolled namely George,Lisa,Mathias and Math Class, 4 students enrolled Peter,George,Anna,Martin.

```
my %register=();

$register{$className}->{$count_students}=$student_name; # Fill the hash.

  foreach my $key ( keys %register ){      

   print "$key: ";

   foreach my $class ( keys %{ $register{$key} } ){

       print "$class=$register{$key}->{$class}\n";

   }  
}
```

I get result like:

Science_class: 2=Lisa
1=George
3=Mathias
Math_class: 2=Anna
1=Martin
3=Peter
4=George

But I want my result as:

Science_class: 3 -> Lisa, George, Mathias
Math_class: 4 -> Anna, Martin, Peter, George

How do I correct my script? Help me out.

Comment: Will there be more than one `$count_students` per class (ie. more than one science class)?

Comment: I dint understand your question but there are more than one class like Science Math English an so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the number of entries in the second level with the [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) function in scalar context, and you can get just the values in the second level with the [`values`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/values.html) function.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %register = (
    Science_class => {
        1 => "George",
        2 => "Lisa",
        3 => "Mathias",
    },
    Math_class => {
        1 => "Martin",
        2 => "Anna",
        3 => "Peter",
        4 => "George",
    }
);

for my $class (keys %register) {
    print "$class: ", scalar keys %{$register{$class}},
        " ", join(", ", values %{$register{$class}}), "\n";
}
```

However, given the structure of your data, a hash of arrayrefs makes more sense:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %register = (
    Science_class => [
        "George",
        "Lisa",
        "Mathias",
    ],
    Math_class => [
        "Martin",
        "Anna",
        "Peter",
        "George",
    ]
);

for my $class (keys %register) {
    print "$class: ", scalar @{$register{$class}},
        " ", join(", ", @{$register{$class}}), "\n";
}
```

You may find reading [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) useful in understanding how to create and manipulate data structures in Perl 5.

Answer (score 2):

In a scalar context, keys will return the number of keys in a hash. In an array context, it returns an array of those keys. You want to print the class's name followed by the number of students in that class before you enter the inner loop, so that you don't print that number more than once.

```
$numkeys = keys $register{$key};
print "$key: $numkeys ->";
```

Followed by the names in that array. There's no need to have an inner loop to display the names, just use keys:

```
print join(", ", keys $register{$key});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to store the number of students in each class, since you can just count the number of students you have in the structure. (And therefore your counts won't get out of sync when your structure changes.) I would recommend using a hash of arrays, like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %register;

# populate the hash, e.g.:
my $classname = 'science_class';
push @{ $register{$classname} }, 'Lisa';
push @{ $register{$classname} }, 'George';
push @{ $register{$classname} }, 'Mathias';

# print the results:

foreach my $class( sort keys %register ) { 
    print $class, ' : ';
    my @students = @{ $register{$class};
    print scalar( @students ), ' = ';   # number of elements in the array
    print join ', ', @students;
    print "\n";
}
```